# Git Ahead SSH Error - Failed to clone into 'my directory' - failed to find SSH identity file

Tags: git, ssh, gitahead

I have a remote repository on my local server and I wanted to clone it into my local machine using Git Ahead, and I'm using Windows 10.

I get this error:

```
"Failed to clone into 'my directory' - failed to find SSH identity file".
```

I'm using the username and password authentication, I do not use key-based authentication. I can log in to the remote server with a username and password. The server is a Linux server, and other mac users can use the git properly.

Comment: What does `ssh -Tv <server>` output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and follow [`gitahead/gitahead` issue 465](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues/465):

> Before cloning, goto Tools > Options > Misc.
>
> Specify the path to the `id_rsa` private key file (or similar key file) in the "`Path to default / fallback SSH key file`" text field.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7346503/88257295-04e14e00-ccdb-11ea-857d-c44c84bdbdcb.png]